# Clear dynamic content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, effects

After loading dynamic content to a DIV, I'd like to add a Close option, that would remove this content from the DOM.

I'm working with jQuery and WordPress.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure! You can use [hide](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide) or [remove](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove) based on your requirements.

```
$("#close_link").click(function() {
  $("#your_div").hide(); 
});
```

or

```
$("#close_link").click(function() {
  $("#your_div").remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove elements form a page.  If say your element's ID was 'foo' then you could do it like this

```
$('#foo').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.remove()` function will do the trick.  The question is what to remove.  If your dynamic content has some particular class, you could do something like this:

```
$(".stuff-to-remove").remove();
```

It sounds like you'll be generating the "Close" link dynamically too, so your code might look something like:

```
var div = $('<div></div>');
// ... put stuff in the div...

var close = $('<a href="#"></a>').click(function() {
    div.remove();
    return false;
});
div.append(close);
```

Here there's no need to find the dynamic content, since you already have ready access to it in a variable.